# Checkbox in dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a table in excel where I can select multiple items from a dropdown list in one cell.

Now, using my macro I have to pick all of the options separately, and they are added to a cell one by one.

Is there a possibility to write the macro that adds checkboxes to the dropdown list, so I could check the items I want to add and they will be added simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a form listbox and allow multiple selections. [Check here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-HP010236681.aspx) for MS support.

VBA - check [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274382/excel-listbox-multi-selection)

Comment: OK I did as you suggested, it works but i have one more problem: The elements that I Choose appear one ofter another (when I choose test1 and test2 it shows in a cell like "test1test2), is there a possibility to chenage it somwhere in listbox properties, to, for example put it with a comma (test1, test2)?

Comment: Using an activeX control and VBA? Are you concatenating the output?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used this code for the Listbox:

```
Dim lngItem As Long
Const strSep = ", " 'delimiter

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ListBox1
    .RowSource = "=Sheet1!A2:A12"
    For lngItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        .Selected(lngItem) = InStr(1, strSep & ActiveCell.Value & strSep, strSep & .List(lngItem, 0) & strSep)
    Next lngItem
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strItems As String
With ListBox1
    For lngItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(lngItem) Then
            strItems = strItems & strSep & ListBox1.List(lngItem, 0)
        End If
    Next lngItem
End With
With ActiveCell
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Replace(strItems, strSep, "", 1, 1)
End With
Unload Me
End Sub
```

and this one for columns selection:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column <> 3 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
UserForm1.Show
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

It works great, but I would like to change one thing.

At the moment, the listbox shows up after double-clicking the cell, is there a possibility to make it just one-click? Also can it be changed so that the listbox would always show up below selected cell?

Answer (score -1):

If you look into the attached image, you will know that this is what the prefect solution looks like. Using chekboxes inside listboxes.

[image]

Download the code:
http://www.vlsiip.com/exceltips.html

Comment: If you post a link to a web site that you own,  you must say that it is yours.

Comment: Yes, it is my web site. I own www.vlsiip.com

Comment: Yes, I know (but thanks for acknowledging it).  You may mention it in [your profile page](https://superuser.com/users/821852/aviral-mittal) without restriction, because we assume that everything in your profile page is about you.  What I’m telling you is that [***every time*** you mention the site in an answer (or a question), you *must* say that it is yours ***in the post***](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) — doing it in a comment is not enough.  Also, you should not mention it in every answer you write (I would say, off the top of my head, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  that you should limit yourself to about 20% — but that’s not official) and you should definitely avoid [adding it to somebody else’s answer](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/709117).   Excessive promotion of your own web site will be seen as [spam](https://superuser.com/help/promotion), and will lead to [answers being deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers), [new answers being blocked (refused)](https://superuser.com/help/abuse-block), and possibly the deletion of your account.   I advise you to [take the site “tour”](/tour) to get an overview of the rules.

Comment: P.S. I almost forgot to mention: when you answer a question on [SU], you should **answer the question *on Super User***. Posts that say “yes, it’s possible; follow this link to see how” are unacceptable and will be deleted, even if the link is to somewhere like microsoft.com or mozilla.org. If you want to control who sees your code and other pearls of wisdom, then maybe [SU] isn’t the place for you.   P.P.S. Your site has many typos: “i” (should be “I”), Lets (→ Let’s), wont (→ won’t), ahve (→ have), anywehre, deliberatly, doubble, follwing, mulitple, Selet, shd, Shee1, th3, Toolsbox, welcome.